# How to bring model predict line in front of geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I am investigating the effect of time since fire on species diversity. I am attempting to make a graph that has different colours at different time since fire ages. However, putting the colours onto the graph has made the model prediction line fade away. I am wondering if there is some way to bring the line in front of geom_rect?

Loaded packages:

```
library(voxel)
library(gamm4)
library(ggplot2)
```

My data:

```
data <- read.csv('StacksOverflow.csv')

 structure(list(Lscape = c(158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L), 
    TSF = c(5, 5, 5, 18.5, 5, 18.5), VegtypeNew = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("spinsandplain", "woodlndsandplain"
    ), class = "factor"), FF = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), ThreeYearRain = c(913.799997, 
    913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997
    ), Div = c(2.2629743, 1.9630117, 1.7336569, 1.2816843, 2.4155056, 
    1.4240443), triodia_low = c(19L, 6L, 21L, 32L, 11L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Extended data:

```
structure(list(Lscape = c(158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 
158L, 158L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 235L, 
235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 
237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 
254L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 304L, 304L, 
304L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 311L, 311L, 311L, 311L, 311L, 
311L, 311L, 311L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 
323L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 326L, 326L, 326L, 
326L, 326L, 326L, 326L, 326L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 
327L, 327L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 355L, 
355L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 
370L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 
379L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 414L, 414L, 
414L, 414L, 414L, 414L, 414L, 414L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 435L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 
438L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 
447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 
452L, 452L), TSF = c(5, 5, 5, 18.5, 5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 11.5, 
4.5, 0.5, 20, 11.5, 0.5, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 4.5, 5, 4.5, 2, 5, 1, 
6, 6, 4.5, 6, 14.5, 17, 4.5, 6, 1, 1, 7, 4.5, 2, 2, 7, 7, 20, 
4, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 11.5, 20, 6, 0.5, 5, 6, 6, 0.5, 7, 6, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 11.5, 11.5, 1, 1, 11.5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 10.5, 
7, 17.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 17.5, 7, 0.5, 18, 1.5, 3.5, 18, 18, 5, 
3.5, 18.5, 14.5, 1.5, 7, 1.5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10.5, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 
7, 3, 7, 10.5, 0.5, 20, 0.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 2, 3, 20, 1, 1.5, 10.5, 
17, 1.5, 1.5, 10.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4.5, 1, 6.5, 1, 10, 1.5, 12.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 7, 12.5, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 18.5, 
18.5, 1.5, 7, 1.5, 1.5, 5, 12.5, 6.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 6.5, 6.5, 1.5, 6.5, 18.5, 6.5, 7, 1.5, 1, 7, 7, 1, 7, 1, 
7.5, 7.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), VegtypeNew = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("spinsandplain", "woodlndsandplain"
), class = "factor"), FF = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L
), ThreeYearRain = c(913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 
913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 913.799997, 938.899988, 938.899988, 
938.899988, 938.600004, 938.899988, 938.899988, 938.899988, 938.499989, 
930.700005, 932.800001, 930.700005, 930.700005, 932.800001, 930.700005, 
930.700005, 932.800001, 932.699991, 934.799987, 934.799987, 934.799987, 
932.699991, 934.799987, 932.699991, 934.799987, 896.99999, 896.99999, 
908.999991, 908.999991, 908.999991, 908.999991, 910.199991, 898.399994, 
928.000009, 939.800006, 935.500004, 928.000009, 928.000009, 923.700007, 
931.499996, 931.499996, 866.200004, 866.200004, 867.000003, 867.000003, 
867.000003, 867.300002, 867.000003, 869.3, 926.800003, 926.800003, 
926.800003, 926.800003, 933.800003, 934.600006, 934.600006, 934.600006, 
924.2, 925.100002, 924.2, 924.2, 924.2, 922.2, 924.2, 924.7, 
974.799995, 983.500006, 983.500006, 983.500004, 983.500006, 974.799995, 
974.799994, 983.500006, 839.1, 839.1, 839.1, 839.100001, 839.300001, 
839.1, 838.699999, 839.100001, 839.100001, 838.699999, 842.300004, 
842.300004, 842.900006, 842.300004, 842.900006, 842.300004, 936.900014, 
936.900014, 936.900014, 932.999984, 933.099983, 932.999984, 936.900014, 
936.900014, 870.499995, 870.499995, 877.399998, 877.399998, 876.099997, 
876.099997, 876.099997, 859.199997, 957.199982, 966.299982, 955.699998, 
955.699998, 957.199982, 955.699998, 955.699998, 956.299985, 852.2, 
852.2, 852.600006, 852.500001, 852.500001, 852.500001, 852.600006, 
852.500001, 906.700011, 904.700001, 912.600007, 912.600007, 914.600007, 
906.700001, 906.399998, 914.600007, 925.599982, 933.299992, 933.299992, 
933.299992, 933.299992, 926.500012, 935.899994, 935.199992, 916.800001, 
916.100001, 916.800001, 916.400003, 918.700003, 904.100001, 916.800001, 
918.700003, 899.1, 904.100001, 906.000003, 903.400002, 904.100001, 
903.400002, 906.000003, 906.000003, 905.7, 903.099999, 903.099999, 
905.7, 912.199994, 893.200002, 905.399999, 904.999998, 933.700012, 
933.700012, 933.700012, 933.700012, 933.700012, 932.30001, 932.300008, 
932.300008, 878.500006, 878.500006, 878.500006, 879.300004, 879.300004, 
879.300004, 879.300004, 873.200008), Div = c(2.2629743, 1.9630117, 
1.7336569, 1.2816843, 2.4155056, 1.4240443, 1.5178948, 0.8993031, 
1.2022801, 1.9287665, 2.0237769, 2.004871, 1.5020684, 2.1776591, 
2.093787, 2.3139276, 2.7244402, 2.7026829, 1.6644725, 2.0696347, 
1.9561853, 2.6018987, 2.5800017, 2.1867866, 2.4144821, 1.7389892, 
2.1427451, 1.6544538, 1.8651966, 1.7569776, 1.8257533, 1.4048204, 
2.7384914, 2.9344488, 2.2306909, 2.5085619, 1.8874836, 2.3431509, 
1.8401602, 1.8620274, 1.8038997, 2.5909049, 2.2265328, 2.0882065, 
2.4737837, 2.2995223, 1.4231311, 2.0577752, 1.6463134, 2.1464331, 
2.2636437, 2.0992589, 1.7666974, 1.835061, 1.7732171, 2.0813243, 
1.865505, 2.0200607, 1.2510612, 1.021761, 0.8111482, 0.2617645, 
2.0282081, 1.1145976, 2.2596683, 2.3517629, 1.9424972, 1.9191269, 
1.4222035, 2.6007698, 2.0071984, 1.9049132, 1.073374, 0.9576897, 
1.6273043, 1.7701581, 0.6890092, 1.5764456, 0.384906, 1.5099996, 
1.6713486, 2.5483064, 2.2033185, 2.0798843, 1.9082985, 2.1580972, 
1.6952798, 1.6303402, 1.9461221, 1.4116405, 1.5347693, 2.6924921, 
1.727278, 1.9384415, 1.6659585, 1.612819, 1.6592884, 2.7129796, 
0, 2.7098898, 1.3785924, 2.7635218, 1.1481271, 1.8597007, 2.2191531, 
1.088549, 2.431015, 1.3702099, 2.1018035, 2.3442348, 2.3599146, 
2.789816, 1.8340235, 1.0606126, 2.5852679, 1.7791063, 1.2273106, 
2.2432636, 2.5642458, 1.3306642, 2.6771856, 1.5062567, 2.0903266, 
2.0398412, 2.4821503, 0.5979376, 1.479214, 1.9188301, 1.2267089, 
2.4491421, 1.5366949, 2.516592, 2.4084849, 2.4385928, 2.549348, 
2.7090074, 2.3337573, 1.8982968, 1.7956341, 2.3752386, 1.6587394, 
2.6663039, 2.4853204, 1.9325793, 2.4431141, 1.6976331, 0.8791745, 
2.6625573, 1.9596877, 1.9287565, 2.4590816, 2.4963942, 1.8767916, 
1.3954333, 2.5155936, 2.2327274, 2.6613726, 2.580748, 2.3142567, 
2.2280879, 1.7925025, 1.663008, 2.3488945, 2.0746398, 1.7050203, 
2.0108246, 1.7317251, 2.4936515, 0.9556999, 1.3716151, 2.0694067, 
1.4944032, 1.0984774, 1.2868726, 1.6429103, 1.3720737, 1.8037795, 
1.8745583, 1.8921264, 1.8320377, 1.201682, 1.8489571, 1.798546, 
0.8486856), triodia_low = c(19L, 6L, 21L, 32L, 11L, 32L, 16L, 
29L, 17L, 20L, 0L, 24L, 37L, 0L, 3L, 29L, 4L, 2L, 31L, 28L, 20L, 
12L, 6L, 6L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 26L, 15L, 27L, 2L, 1L, 
19L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 33L, 14L, 25L, 22L, 15L, 34L, 15L, 7L, 36L, 
25L, 25L, 0L, 25L, 4L, 21L, 0L, 33L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 22L, 25L, 
25L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 2L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 13L, 28L, 35L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 29L, 0L, 14L, 5L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 
22L, 7L, 23L, 10L, 23L, 17L, 19L, 7L, 27L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 29L, 14L, 
30L, 12L, 0L, 35L, 0L, 29L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 15L, 33L, 0L, 3L, 21L, 
34L, 0L, 2L, 28L, 16L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 27L, 2L, 
28L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 14L, 27L, 25L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 16L, 9L, 
4L, 15L, 40L, 2L, 18L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 33L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 
7L, 3L, 17L, 30L, 5L, 7L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 0L, 26L, 16L, 0L, 
24L, 1L, 27L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-184L))
```

The model:

```
m1b <-gamm4(Div~TSF+FF+s(triodia_low, k=6)+VegtypeNew+ThreeYearRain,random=~(1|Lscape),data=data)
```

Plotting:

```
p <-plotGAMM (m1b,smooth.cov="triodia_low",groupCovs = NULL,orderedAsFactor=T,rawOrFitted="raw",plotCI=T,grouping = NULL)
p + labs(x= "Years since fire") +
  labs(y="Species diversity (H')") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour="black")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=22)) +    # face="bold"
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,40,by=5)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0,xmax=0.6,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.002, fill="coral4") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=.6,xmax=1,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.002, fill="gold") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=1,xmax=5,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.002, fill="darkred") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=5,xmax=10,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.002,fill="chocolate") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=10,xmax=40,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),alpha=0.002,fill="orangered") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=18, colour="black")) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial")) +
  theme(legend.position= "none")
```

The plot:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As far as I have observed, ggplot draws the geoms in the order you are calling them - so, if you move the plotGamm after the geom_rects, you should get your desired result.

Comment: How do I do that if there is no plot if i dont first define what p is though?

Comment: Layers are drawn in order. I'm not aware of any easy way to change this. You could look into the `plotGAMM` function - hopefully it is not too complicated and you can copy code out to run after the `geom_rect`

Comment: Can you post a bit more data so one can actually fit the GAMM? You should be able to generate this fairly easily in my *gratia* package but I haven't tested it much with *gamm4* models and would like to check things work before suggesting an answer

Comment: @RichardTelford thank you for your suggestion, I shall try. I am very new at using plotGAMM too and struggling to find an answer.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson I have posted a bit more data, is that sufficient? Hmm okay, I shall check in on the gratia package. Thank you

Comment: @LeanneGreenwild Can you dput() the data as you did first the first snippet?

Comment: Hi @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson is that better?

Comment: @RichardTelford the gratia package is only for GAMs (mgcv package) isnt it? And the voxel package for GAMMs (gamm4 package)?

Comment: @LeanneGreenwild no *gratia* should work with GAM(M)s fitted by mgcv, or gamm4.

Comment: @LeanneGreenwild Thanks for posting the extra data. I have posted an answer now and will soon push the needed code to the development version of gratia in GitHub. There were a few things missing for gamm4 models, which I've now added to the package.

Answer (score 0):

Using the development version of *gratia* you can replicate the plot you showed with a few simple calls to create the data, predict etc.

To install the development version of *gratia* do

```r
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("gavinsimpson/gratia")
```

Once installed you can produce an object suitable for plotting using:

```r
library('mgcv')
library('gamm4')
library('gratia')
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')

## model fit
m1b <- gamm4(Div ~ TSF + FF + s(triodia_low, k=6) + VegtypeNew + ThreeYearRain,
             random = ~ (1|Lscape), data = df)

## data to predict at
new_df <- data_slice(m1b, var1 = 'triodia_low', n = 100)
## predict and cast to a tibble
pred_df <- as_tibble(predict(m1b[["gam"]], new_df, se.fit = TRUE))
## add to the data we're predicting at
pred_df <- bind_cols(new_df, pred_df)
## grab the inverse link of the model (not needed here, but is for non-Normal fits)
ilink <- inv_link(m1b)
## create the upper and lower credible interval
pred_df <- mutate(pred_df,
                  lwr = ilink(fit - (2 * se.fit)),
                  upr = ilink(fit + (2 * se.fit)),
                  fit = ilink(fit))
```

The plot itself can be created using:

```r
ggplot(pred_df, aes(x = triodia_low, y = fit)) +
    labs(x = "Years since fire", y = "Species diversity (H')") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour="black")) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size=22)) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_line()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,40,by=5)) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=0,   xmax=0.6, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.01, fill="coral4") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=0.6, xmax=1,   ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.01, fill="gold") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=1,   xmax=5,   ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.01, fill="darkred") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=5,   xmax=10,  ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.01, fill="chocolate") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=10,  xmax=40,  ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.01, fill="orangered") +
    geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = triodia_low, y = Div)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.4) +
    geom_line()
```

Most of the *ggplot* code is your's, but now that we have full control, we can put the data layers in the foreground by leaving those layers until the end.

Note that I'm not convinced this is a great plot. The fitted function you are showing is *conditional upon* the other covariates in the data set. Here, and as with `voxel::plotGAMM()`, we're predicting from the model and hence we have to supply something for the other covariates. Following `voxel::plotGAMM` and `mgcv::vis.gam`, we fix the other covariates not shown at

1. the value of the data observation closest to the median (for continuous variables), or
2. the modal category (for factor parametric terms)

So, the resulting figure is the fit conditional upon those values. In particular it is for the `spinsandplain` level of `VegTypeNew`. As such it is a little misleading.